# Javascript game with timer

Tags: javascript, multithreading, concurrency

I'm modifying a Javascript game and need to add a countdown timer (from 3:00 minutes to 0 seconds) at the top of the game board. I have both the game and timer written, the timer will start when the user clicks the "start" button for the game. (ie the game is timed to end after 3 minutes)

My issue is that, since JavaScript is not multi-threaded, my game countdown timer will not be allowed to run (tick) while a user is concurrently playing my game. Is that correct?

It just seemed to me that there would be some way to get this to work, outside of using the new multi-threading JavaScript libraries.

**Here's my timer:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// set minutes
var mins = 3;
// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;

function countdown() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}

function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.value = getminutes();
            seconds.value = getseconds();
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
}

function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}

function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}
</script>

<script>
countdown();
</script>


<div id="timer">
    <input id="minutes" value="3" type="text" style="width: 14px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">:<input id="seconds" value="00" type="text" style="width: 26px; border: none; background-color:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;"> remaining
</div>
```

Here's the portion of my game that kicks everything off:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#button-start").click(game.start);
});
</script>
```

How do I have the `game.start` method run as well as the `countdown()` method from my timer? Everytime I try to run both of the methods when "start" is clicked, the JavaScript doesn't run at all. Nothing works and it freezes up, I assume from two methods trying to run at once?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Timers still run regardless.

Comment: How are we suppose to help without your code? Are you using a for loop for the countdown instead of setTimeout?

Comment: "Playing the game" is not a synchronous, browser-freezing 3-minute-lasting script execution, is it? The timer will have a chance to fire during the event loop.

Comment: @Bergi It's an interactive game, it constantly changes images (once every 2 seconds) and requires the user to press keyboard buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);`

when I should have been using `setTimeout(Decrement,1000);`

Removing the single quotes and parenthesis after "Decrement" solved my problem.

Comment: Credit for answer goes to Plato, who mentioned this in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You should just use `setTimeout`, then it won't block

```
var initialTime = new Date();
function updateTimer() {
    if (new Date() - initialTime > (1000 * 1000 * 60 * 3) ) {
         document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = formatTime();
         setTimeout(updateTimer, 1000);    
    }
}
updateTimer();
```

Just don't use a busy loop

Comment: I used setTimeout but it doesn't seem to be working. See added code for more info.

Comment: @Plato My syntax is wrong? From your comment it looks like your comment is for the OP

Comment: Plato is correct, MY syntax was wrong, correcting setTimeout as it's shown above solved my problem.

Comment: @Plato Feel free to mimic my self-accepted answer and post something similar as an answer, I'll select yours instead, you should get credit for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your game uses some sort of a busy loop, i.e., something like this:

```
while (1) {
    // process next event
}
```

… then you shouldn't need to worry about it. Your JavaScript engine will automatically interleave user events with timer events, so the timer *shouldn't* get starved.

Answer (score 1):

one way:

```
var S_LEFT = 180;
function myTicker(){
  console.log('tick');
  S_LEFT -= 1;
  if(S_LEFT === 0) doSomething();
  $('#seconds').html(S_LEFT);
};

$('#start').on('click', function(){
  window.setInterval(myTicker, 1000);
});
```

@Juan Mendes's way using setTimeout and no Jquery:

```
var S_LEFT = 180;
function tick(){
  console.log('tick');
  S_LEFT -= 1;
  if(S_LEFT === 0){ 
    alert('Boom');
  } else {
    document.body.innerHTML = S_LEFT;
    window.setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
};
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',tick,false);
tick();
```

Comment: Post your answer and I'll accept it, your SetTimeout correct solved my problem.

Comment: @JuanMendes, looks like the OP is using jQuery to me... (see bottom of his original question)

Comment: @mattburns That wasn't there in the original question

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers seem way too complex for me.

Why not simply get a timestamp in seconds upon first starting the timer using

```
var beginTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

Then make your end

```
var endTimestamp = beginTimestamp + (3*60)
```

Then on update, get the number of seconds remaining with

```
var numSecondsRemaining = endTimestamp - Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)
```

and finally

```
if(numSecondsRemaining <= 0) { /* end game */ }
```

To format, just do

```
var date = new Date(numSecondsRemaining*1000);
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
var formattedTime = minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
```

This approach isn't affected by any funkiness that setTimeout might be prone to. It's also much smaller, and requires basically no math.